# Static files aren't deploying in developer mode

Tags: magento2, 404, static-content, less-css

I am using `Magento 2` (developer mode) and I just created a new theme, added a `local-l.css` to my `/var/www/vendor/app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/web/css/source/local-l.css` and when I refresh the homepage it says

> 404 GET 
>   http://www.vendor.dev/pub/static/version1486248173/frontend/vendor/theme/en_US/css/local-l.css

`app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
<head>
    <css src="css/local-l.css" />
</head>
</page>
```

And doesn't load my styles.. I tried clearing `cache`, `view_preprocessed`, `pub/static/*`, everything and I tried redeploying using `static:mode:deploy`... nothing is working for me.

Any ideas?

Comment: Seem that your custom css puts wrong place, it should be under `web/css` folder : `app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/web/css/local-l.css`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem that your custom css put wrong place, it should be under `web/css` folder in your custom theme : `app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/web/css/local-l.css`.

Remember to run static content deploy again.

Answer (score 4):

You have "`Sign Static Files`" options set to `Yes` in your backend : http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/static-file-signature.html

`Magento 2` add `versionXXXXXXX` to his URL to avoid "extrem" browser caching.
Browser cache URLs with `versionXXXXXXX` in it so when there is a new release of static content `Magento` set URLs to `versionYYYY` to force content cache to be renewed.

For comparison is like `?version=XXXX` for `Wordpress` files.

You have 2 solutions :
1. Set `Sign Static Files` option to `No`
2. Add this line to you host configuration (*here NGINX*) : https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/nginx.conf.sample#L101

```
location /static/ {
    # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
    location ~ ^/static/version {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static/$2 last;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou!!!!! <3